# evitar que los espacios vacíos cambien a %20

Tags: javascript, java, script

estoy utilizando un archivo externo de `js` y desde mi `_layout` principal le envío un parámetro desde la etiqueta `<script>` de esta manera:

```
<script id='identificador_js' src="~/Public/SweetAlertMsg.js?mensaje=@ViewData["Msg"]"></script>
```

el valor de `@ViewData["Msg"]` es "usuario añadido con éxito"

para obtener el parámetro `mensaje` desde la etiqueta script, en mi fichero `js` externo hago lo siguiente:

```
var Mensaje = document.getElementById("identificador_js").src.split("mensaje=")[1];

alert(qs);
```

esto me imprime: `usuario%20añadido%20con%20éxito`.

Como puedo evitar que se me reemplacen los espacios en blanco del `string` por los %20?.

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mensajeDecoded = decodeURIComponent(Mensaje);

alert(mensajeDecoded);
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono sin problemas :D